# Add remove tr td row without click open 4 field and after click one by one open?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I  need to add remove tr td row without click onload 4 tr td row open after click one by one open tr td row all need script not need static. please help..

**html code**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
   <table id="table-details"></table>
   <button class="btn-add-more">Add Rows</button>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
$("body").on('click', '.btn-add-more', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var rows = $(".jdr1").length;
  var limit = 1;
  // In the first click append 3 rows, then 1 row per click
  if (rows < 3) limit = 3;
   for (let i=0; i<limit; i++) {
      var $sr = ($(".jdr1").length + 1);
      var rowid = Math.random();
      var $html = '<tr class="jdr1" id="' + rowid + '">' +
           '<td><span class="btn btn-sm btn-default">' + $sr + '</span><input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1)+'"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-sm title" placeholder="Medicine" name="medicine[]"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" name="medicine_qty[]" placeholder="Potency" class="form-control input-sm"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" name="medicine_time[]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control input-sm"></td>' +
           '<td><input type="text" name="remark[]" placeholder="Add/Note" class="form-control input-sm"></td>' + '<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning btn-remove-detail-row"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Remove</i></button>    </td>'+
           '</tr>';
   
   $("#table-details").append($html);
   }
})
```

Comment: Not sure what you are saying ..please elaborate more .

Comment: onload open 4 field after click one by one tr td row open

Comment: You can use `$(".btn-add-more").click();` to trigger your click event on load . Working fiddle check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j9pes2Lv/)

Comment: thanku for help work is fine